# Looking for a micro programmable FPGA + machine

Tags: cpu, fpga

I'm looking for a FPGA + machine.

It should be entry level pricing (e.g no more than $200).

EDIT: I want to make an ASM chart and program the FPGA to act like I specified in the chart

Comment: Are you looking for a general purpose CPU or something more raw like a FPGA? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPGA

Comment: You might be better off asking this question at chiphacker.com

Comment: Half of the answers on here for microprocessors / microcontrollers, which is != FPGA.  Which confuses me about why you find the Arduino interesting.

Comment: The OP originally asked for a CPU - hence all the arduino answers

Comment: @Martin - Ah.  Should've checked the edits.

Comment: If you are planning to design with a chart you are probably looking for a more basic device like a CPLD, e.g. http://www.simpledigitalcomputer.com/PLDGettingStarted.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/)?

Comment: Which is an AVR. There is no Arduino processor :-/

Comment: @theatrus - it has a microcontroller on board.

Comment: where can i find a FPGA for the Arduino board?

Comment: @~konman - You may find some info here: http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1239761480/9

Answer (score 3):

What about this one? [IGEPv2 Board](http://www.igep-platform.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46&Itemid=55)

It runs very smooth. We have web server running on it and it's about the size of a credit card.

There is another similar project: http://beagleboard.org/, which is an open-source hardware and costs about the same as IGEP.

Comment: The Machine cycles of the ARM Cortex-A8 can not be altered (at least not with software) which is used in the Beagle.

Answer (score 3):

I would try the [NEXYS](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavTop=2&NavSub=451&Prod=NEXYS2) for an FPGA.

To everyone else: the Aruino isn't an FPGA. It's a hardware specification/programming framework that uses the atmega microcontroller line.

Answer (score 2):

Atmel sells a device with a 5-20k gate FPGA integrated with an 8bit AVR core.

http://www.atmel.com/products/fpslic/

Also, for everyone recommending microcontrollers like the Arduino platform and BASIC stamp: They are **not** FPGAs.

Comment: Sadly, the FPSLIC doesn't include synthesis software. The starter kit only includes that for six months. I'd lean towards Xilinx for that reason, but the competition are beginning to offer tools - if you can get them working.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this:

http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/AES-S6MB-LX9.htm

or

http://www.altera.com/b/nios-bemicro-evaluation-kit.html

Xilinx, Altera, and Lattice all have inexpensive ( < $200) FPGA development cards.  Based on your stated needs just about any of them would do.  If all you need is to implement a state machine a CPLD would even fit your needs.  Without knowing more it would be hard to recommend an exact card.  Based on the series of edits in your question it would probably be good to go through some introduction to fpga online training.

Some resources:

http://www.xilinx.com/csi/training/basic-hdl-coding-techniques-part1.htm

http://www.fpga4fun.com/

or search for "fpga tutorial" with the search engine of your choice

Answer (score 0):

You can also try NEXYS 2 (its the successor of the NEXYS board). It do have more RAM and some more Gadgets :)

The documentation(of the FPGA from Xilinx) is just great and big and there are some example-projects out there for this board.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider somewhat of a blend here. Gadget factory offer the [Papilio One](http://www.gadgetfactory.net/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=18), which is an FPGA development board with an Arduino microcontroller as the first example. You can then choose to blend the two as you wish. The downsides are that it has less ready-made peripherals, such as ADCs, buttons, or LEDs, and that the low voltage circuitry cannot withstand 5V. There's a bunch of (more expensive) addons to fix that, though.

I'm not sure what you mean by an ASM chart, but there are schematic and flowchart programming tools around, for instance in Webpack or Great Cow Graphical Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Opal Kelly sell some great USB FPGA dev kits for a reasonable price. Along with the hardware, they also ship the RTL (FPGA logic) to allow your design to communicate via USB and a C based API to allow your software on the other side to talk to the FPGA design.